# Prerender component / route on hover or call

Tags: reactjs, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-redux` and would like to create a new custom `NavLink` or `Link` that preloads components for the hovered Link Route upon hover. I would be greatful for some help to point me into the right direction.

I have no idea how to accomplish mounting the component defined in the route without routing to it.

Basicly if I am at the root url of page and hover over a `<Link to="/portfolio" />` I want the matched component defined in my routes to prefetch the data needed for this page so that when a user finally clicks the link the data would already be served.

I haven no issues creating a HOC to add eventlisteners to the Link's and then dispatch an action but I need help on how to mount the routes without actually routing to them.

Answer (score 1):

`react-loadable` sounds like what you want.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable

Comment: I dont need code-splitting though. All routes/components should come in a single bundle, however what im trying to accomplish is to mount the hovered link's route so the component matching can dispatch the actions needed in order to show data when user finally clicks the link. 

Lets say im at startpage, and user hovers over "About us", I want the component to mount & then dipatch the actions defined in that matched component BEFORE user routes to the page.

Comment: The package has a preload method thats exposed when created by `Loadable` but if thats not going to work for you I'm sorry I can't really think of a way to achieve the desired outcome. :/